# window.onbeforeunload not working in android mobile/ ipad / iphone browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anyone can you please help to work this issue. I have tried many solution for it. I want to fire event when browser close. I tried below codes for solutions but every solutions only work in desktop.

```
            window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                    if (imgArray.length != 0)
                        pms_image_clock.addimglog(true);
                };

            window.pagehide = function () {
                if (imgArray.length != 0)
                    pms_image_clock.addimglog(true);
            };
```

Also tried below

```
jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload pagehide onunload', function(e) {
           if (imgArray.length != 0)
                        pms_image_clock.addimglog(true);
});
```

And this also

```
window.onunload = window.pagehide = window.onbeforeunload = function() {
             if (imgArray.length != 0)
                    pms_image_clock.addimglog(true);
}
```

Anyone have solution that browser close event work in mobile/ipad browser. Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, did you find any answer to this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @RaefKandil yes

Comment: That is very good. How did it get resolved for you?

Comment: @RaefKandil I have tried this code.. and working for me

window.addEventListener("blur", function (e) {
     if (imgArray.length != 0)
      pms_image_clock.addimglog(true);
    }, false);
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
     if (imgArray.length != 0)
      pms_image_clock.addimglog(true);
    }, false);

Comment: @RaefKandil its working for you ?

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: @RaefKandil can i help you ?

Comment: t@Jalpa, thank you very much. I am using AngularJS. For the full question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47150350/angularjs-window-onbeforeunload-is-not-working-on-android-and-iphone . I would be very happy if you can help me.