# AngularJS window.onbeforeunload is not working on Android and Iphone

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, iphone, onbeforeunload

I am using the following code:-

```
 .directive('confirmOnExitForm', function() {
        return {
            link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
                window.onbeforeunload = function(){
                    if ($scope.form.$dirty) {
                        return "The form is dirty, do you want to stay on the page?";
                    }
                }

            }
        };
    })
```

This code is working fine on Desktops Chrome and Safari, but it is not working for Android and Iphones.

Any idea why?

Comment: please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127621/is-there-any-way-to-use-window-onbeforeunload-on-mobile-safari-for-ios-devices

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239834/window-onbeforeunload-not-working-on-the-ipad?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Please try above solutions and let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [window.onbeforeunload not working on the iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239834/window-onbeforeunload-not-working-on-the-ipad)